# AWS storage gateway with SQL Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-storage-gateway

I'm looking over the AWS service Storage Gateway.

After looking over some videos, I learned that Storage Gateway offers 3 types of gateways: file, tape and volume.

On the AWS side, we are able to store data in S3, EBs, etc.

For my particular scenario - let's say I have a dozen MS SQL Server tables I want to back up to AWS. I don't really need to access this data often, however might need to query it once in a while.

Is storage gateway to right way to go about this? I understand that if I store data in S3 I can run AWS Glue which can categorize my data and what not - and later I can use `Athena` to query my S3 buckets. However if I wanted the data to be stored in RDS, would I use Storage Gateway in that scenario?

> EDIT: I think I answered my own question. I guess I can use AWS Glue
> to ETL the data from S3 buckets into RDS of my choice if I just add
> some roles. Does this sound correct?

In additional - in case I lose my on-premise data in those tables I backed up - can I somehow restore the data as it was from the last back up done in AWS.

Please correct me if any of my "understanding" is incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have an easy way to directly query MS SQL data inside S3, even with Glue. Glue can be used when you have plaintext-based objects (CSV, JSON...) inside S3

You can use File gateway or Volume gateway in stored mode. Creating the backup files from MS SQL is still your responsibility as well as attemping a restoration. The only thing storage gateway help in this case is to retain one copy of your data remotely